# How to debug a base csp minidriver

Tags: windows, debugging, device-driver, smartcard

I'd like to attach a debugger to a base csp minidriver on windows 7.
Which process hosts the driver .dll? Is it just another WUDFHost.exe ?
Can I attach a user-mode debugger to that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least when using [certutil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624045%28WS.10%29.aspx) the .dll is loaded "directly" into the process.
In Visual Studio one can set `certutil.exe` as the command in the Debugging panel and then step into the minidriver.dll's code and thereby test how certutil tries to access the smartcard.

Comment: Could you provide some additional information on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did simple stupid logging instead of debuging of my minidriver.

Testing your minidriver with `certutil` is easy:

```
certutil.exe -SCInfo
```

The idea of debugging a minidriver is bias.
For windows 10 there is a **5 second timeout** to operate with a card. If you don't poll the card for 5 second you get your card reset by the operating system.

Here is how the error looks:

> The card in Smart Card Reader 'Generic EMV Smartcard Reader 0' has been reset because an application held an exclusive transaction
>   on the card for 5 seconds without activity.  If this error persists,
>   the application may not be functioning correctly.

Here is what [Microsoft says](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849637(v=ws.11).aspx) about it:

> Smart card transactions On Windows Server 2012, Windows 8, and Windows
>   RT, if a transaction is held on the card for more than 5 seconds with
>   no operations happening on the card, the card is reset. This is a
>   change from the behavior in previous releases.

For healthy debugging you have to introduce a separate thread that polls your card status with `SCardStatus` or `SCardGetAttrib` as [Gemalto does](http://support.gemalto.com/index.php?id=withwindows8myapplicationl)

> To avoid the system resetting the smart card after the 5-second
>   timeout, Gemalto recommends you  regularly call a transparent function
>   like SCardStatus or SCardGetAttrib, using a timer, after calling
>   SCardBeginTransaction. This change also applies to Windows 8, RT and
>   Server 2012 systems.